# How can I get total plugin downloads history?

Tags: wordpress.org

I am trying to get total downloads history of plugins. 
However, the downloads.php (as below) does only allow 730 days (2 years).
Is there anyways that I can get more than 2 years of data?
Thanks in advance!

https://api.wordpress.org/stats/plugin/1.0/downloads.php?slug=slugname&limit=730&callback=?

Comment: I doubt if there's a complete history but there's a way to get the total downloads http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/jetpack.json `> JSON.parse(document.body.innerText).downloaded`

Comment: Thanks @SamuelElh ... at least I got the total downloads. Is there anyways that I can take a look at the detailed of the downloads.php? I really need to get the history